# PHP counting the letters in a word (HANGMAN)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a hangman game. I have a few words in an array and when one of them is picked I want to count how many letters are in that word so that it can then make that amount of spaces or dashes. Also I need an efficient way to put each letter of the word onto the screen. Each letter is to be invisible, so then when the letter is guessed it will be made visible.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Hangman </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hangman <h1>   
<?php
session_start(); 
$maxAttempts = 6; 
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
?>
<form name="lettersubmit" method="post" action="Hangman.php" > 
<input name="letterguess" type= "text" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Guess a Letter!"><br>
<p> Guesses Remaining <p>
<input name="triesRemaining" type="text" value="<?php print("$maxAttempts"); ?>">
</form>
<?php
$letterguess = $_POST["letterguess"];

if($letterguess= $word){
    echo ("correct");
}
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $words  = array (
    "giants",
    "triangle",
    "particle",
    "birdhouse",
    "minimum",
    "flood",

    $word = $words[array_rand($words)];
);
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $maxAttempts--;
}

$word = $words[array_rand($words)];
    echo $words[array_rand($words)];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code what have you done till now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort.

Comment: Ok just give me a few seconds

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this and I struggle to use the programming terminology that people on this site are familiar with.

Comment: Just a comment: NEVER use `if($letterguess= $word){...` to compare values. That's an assignment! For comparison always use `if($letterguess == $word){... `. Assignment: `=`. Equal value: `==`. Identical: `===`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is still in an early stage. You need to store some of your values, or it will not work. See the [session reference](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) in the manual.

Your actual problem can be solved with this:

```
// these both must be stored (see php session)
$letters_guessed_correct = array('g', 's', 'a');
$word = "giants"; // the current word which is searched for

foreach(str_split($word) as $char) {
    if (in_array($char, $letters_guessed_correct, true)) {
        echo $char;
    } else {
        echo '_';
    }
}
```

This will output

```
g_a__s
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of letters in a string you can use `strlen()` or in multibyte environments `mb_strlen()`.